# How can I update with a form using MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm lost on MySQLi. Manages a blog on standard mysql query, MySqli threw me. Followed a tutorial for inserting into a database. Notice the link for Edit. Not sure how to jump to a edit page to update. It this the wrong way of doing it? I think it's the echo that is the echo that is the issue?

```
        <?php
$sql = "
SELECT snippets.Title, snippets.Link, snippets.Text, snippets.Created, camp_names.ribbon as Ribbon, camp_names.alt_text, camp_names.name as Campaign, camp_names.id
FROM snippets
LEFT JOIN camp_names ON snippets.Campaign = camp_names.id
ORDER BY camp_names.id ASC
";

$results = $db->query($sql);

if($results->num_rows) {
    While($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "

<div class='snippets'>
    <div class='title'><h5><a href=''>{$row->Campaign}</a></h5><strong>{$row->Title}</strong> - Created:{$row->Created}</div>
    <div class='ribbon_wrapper'>
        <div class='ribbon'><img src='{$row->Ribbon}' alt='{$row->alt_text}' /></div>
        <div class='ribbon_text'>{$row->Text}...<a href='{$row->Link}'> Read more</a></div>
        <a href='#'>edit</a>
    </div>
</div>  

";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Results';
}
?>
```

Comment: HTML 101 `<a href='edit.php'>edit</a>`

Comment: You win the aware for most misleading question today

Comment: @developerwjk you win the award for the best typo in comment today

Comment: probably you want to include the id in the echo `echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$row->id}'>edit</a>";`

Comment: Thanks developerwjk. So using that would define the record. In the edit page I have:
<br/>

<code>
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE snippets SET
   Title = ?,
   Text = ?,
   Link = ?, 
   Campaign = ?
   WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss',
   $_POST['Title'],
   $_POST['Text'],
   $_POST['Link'],
   $_POST['Campaign']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
</code>
'Undefined variable: mysqli'
Any ideas?
I have the form after this <code>value"<?php echo $_post[0]['Link']; ?></code> set as values to bring through the text I'm going to edit. These are also going to error for some reason.